# How to replace an integer in Python without using int()

Tags: python

I'm learning Python from Brian Heinold's A Practical Introduction to Python Programming where exercise 24 in chapter 6 reads:

> In calculus, the derivative of *x*<sup>4</sup> is 4*x*<sup>3</sup>. The derivative of *x*<sup>5</sup> is 5*x*<sup>4</sup>. The derivative of *x*6 is 6*x*<sup>5</sup>. This pattern continues. Write a program that asks the user for input like `x^3` or `x^25` and prints the derivative. For example, if the user enters `x^3`, the program should print out `3x^2`.

I figured it out. Easy. However the trick is that should be solved ***without using `int()`*** since it has not been mentioned in the book so far. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Here is my solution:

```
original = input("Enter an x with a power: ")
part1 = original[2:]
part2 = original[0]
part3 = original[1]
part4 = str(int(original[2:])-1)
derivative = part1 + part2 + part3 + part4
print("The derivative is", derivative)
```

Comment: Hard to know what _has_ been mentioned in the book so far. If there's no way to directly convert user input to an int, perhaps you are supposed to manipulate the digit strings (as characters) to build the answer.

Comment: @alexis manually implement addition and subtraction for string integer digits?

Comment: A _practical introduction_ would assume you can research the tools you need, and `int` is a very basic tool (very unlikely it hasn't appeared yet if you're in chapter 6).

Comment: @juanpa, _For example._ No telling what topics the book has covered so far, and what type of contrived problems the author likes to set. (However it's not addition and subtraction, just the `-1` function which is a lot simpler.

Comment: Give us a few minutes while we read the first 6 chapters of the book, to find out what has been mentioned :)

Comment: @alexis I suppose, it is easy enough to write your own `int` to deal with base 10 represented strings but I'm pretty sure the author of the book assumes you can use `int`.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly yes, I agree, it is certainly unlikely that a *practical* introduction to Python would not have mentioned `int`, `str`, `float` etc by chapter 6

Comment: Also, `int` is a data type (i.e. a class, not a function). So if you have seen integers, you have seen it. If not, try a different book.

Comment: No, no ints involved: Just take a string of digits `0123456789` and fetch the one before the last character in the user's input. Special case: if the last character was `0`, then do the right thing.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, sure it will work. It will turn the "5" into a "4". Wrote it out in an answer since it's easier to explain that way.

Comment: Something based on ```for c in original: idx = '0123456789x^ '.index(c)``` should work

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, str, int and float are first explained in chapter 10. I sure have seen int in other books, the reason I'm asking is I want to figure out an alternative way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i'll explain what I meant in the comments. If these are *strings*, not numbers, what is the pattern for subtraction by one? Replace the last digit with the digit just before it in the digit sequence, e.g. turn a final "5" into a "4". Unless it's a zero, in which case do that to the digit before and change the zero to a "9". Like this:

```
digits = "0123456789"
power = "25"     # from user input
last = power[-1]
if last != "0":
    # Subtract from the last digit, e.g. "2" + "4"
    newpower = power[:-1] + digits[digits.index(last)-1]
else:
    # Subtract one from the tens, e.g. 30 -> 29
    tens = power[-2]
    newpower = power[:-2] +  digits[digits.index(tens)-1] + "9"
```

It won't work for numbers ending in *two* zeros like 100, 200 etc., for that you'd need another level or you'd need to turn this into a tricky loop. Left as an exercise to the learner ;-)

Comment: right, essentially, you are using a map to do your subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

My The idea is to use the ASCII value of the digits from 0 to 9 start from 48 – 57.

```
original = input("Enter an x with a power: ")
part1 = original[2:]
part2 = original[0]
part3 = original[1]
c=0
part4 = original[2:]

for i in part4: 
 
    c = c * 10 + (ord(i) - 48) 
part4 = str(c-1)



derivative = part1 + part2 + part3 + part4
print(part4)
print("The derivative is", derivative)
```

output #

```
Enter an x with a power: x^25
The derivative is 25x^24
```